# Trouble querying a collection of a collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm having issues querying for a specific property using linq in EF.

To outline, Users have associated roles.  Each Role has Associated groups.  I'm just trying to get the MAMUserGroup property of all the groups associate with the user.  I can easily get the associate Roles with .Include(), but am having trouble going the one extra level down to the associated MAMUserGroups.

User model:

```
public class User
{
    [Display(Name = "SSO")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(9, ErrorMessage = "SSO must be 9 numbers", MinimumLength = 9)]
    public virtual string ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "MAM Roles")]
    public ICollection<MAMRoleModel> MAMRoles { get; set; }



}
```

MAMRole Model:

```
public class MAMRoleModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MAMUserGroupModels> MAMUserGroups { get; set; }
}
```

MAM Group Model:

```
public class MAMUserGroupModels
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string MAMUserGroup { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried

```
foreach(var bar in user.MAMRoles)
                {
                    foreach(var foo in bar.MAMUserGroups)
                    {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
```

But got null reference error.  I've also just tried from  haim770

```
var test = db.Users.Include(x => x.MAMRoles.Select(y=> y.MAMUserGroups));
```

but MAMUserGroup is a count of 0, so it's not seeing the reference.

Comment: `yourDbSet.Include(user => user.MAMRoles.Select(role => role.MAMUserGroups))`

Comment: Show what you have tried and where it is giving you problems in a [mcve]

Comment: haim770, I'm getting a count of 0 MAMUserGroups with this code.  I went and verified that there is relationship data in my sql object explorer.

Comment: Your entity MAMUserGroupModel does not appear to have any property or reference defined that EF would use to map back to a MAMRoleModel (I.e. a MAMRoleModelId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem arises because you didn't declare your ICollection in the one-to-many relations in entity-framework as virtual. Declaring the ICollection virtual would solve it

To prevent future problems, consider to make your classes more entity-framework compliant. This diminishes the use of all kinds of attributes. Proper use of plurals and singulars improves readability of the queries which helps those who have to change the code in future.

- The primary key 'ID' should not be virtual
- In your one-to-many use the virtual ICollection on the one-side, and add add a reference to the one and the foreign key on your many-side
- Consider using standard naming conventions. This helps entity-framework to define a model without you having to help it using all kinds of attributs.
- Only deviate from the standard naming conventions if you really have to. In that case add Attributes fro primary  key, foreign key, one-to-many relation etc, or consider using fluent API.

.

```
public class User
{
    // Standard naming convention: automatic primary key
    public string ID { get; set; }

    // a user has many MAMRoles.
    // standard naming convention: automatic one-to-many with proper foreign key
    // declare the collection virtual!
    public virtual ICollection<MAMRole> MAMRoles { get; set; }
}

public class MAMRole
{
    // standard naming cause automatic primary key
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // a MAMRole belongs to one user (will automatically create foreign key)
    // standard naming cause proper one-to-many with correct foreign key
    public string UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}

    // A MamRole has many MAMUserGroupModels
    // same one-to-many:
    // again: don't forget to declare the collection virtual
    public virtual ICollection<MAMUserGroupModel> MamUserGroupModels{ get; set; }
}

public class MAMUserGroupModel
{
    // automatic primary  key
    public int ID {get; set;}

    // a MAMUserGroupModel belongs to one MAMUser
    // automatic foreign key
    public int MAMUserId {get; set;}
    public virtual MAMUser MAMUser {get; set;}
}
```

By the way. Entity framework knows it needs to get the value of a property as soon as you use it in your IQueryable. Only if you want to select property values and get them to local memory you'll need to use `Include`. This makes the query more efficient as only the used values are selected.

So if you only want to do something with the `MamUserGroup` inside your `MamUserGroupModel`, don't include anything:

In baby steps:

```
IQueryable<NamRole> mamRolesOfAllUsers = myDbContext.Users
    .SelectMany(user => user.MamRoles);
IQueryable<MamRoleModel> mamUserGroupModelsOfAllUsers = mamRolesOfAllUsers
    .SelectMany(mamRole => mamRole.MamUserGroupModels);
IQueryable<string> mamUserGroups = mamUserGroupModelsOfAllUsers
    .Select(mamUserGroupModel => mamUserGroupModeModel.MamUserGroup;
```

Or in one statement

```
IQueryable<string> mamUserGroups = myDbContext.Users
    .SelectMany(user => user.MamRoles)
    .SelectMany(mamRole => mamRole.MamUserGroupModels)
    .Select(mamUserGroupModel => mamUserGroupModel.MamUserGroup);
```

Note that until know I haven't communicated with the database yet. I've only created the expression of the query. The query will be done once the enumeration starts:

```
foreach(var userGroup in mamUserGroups)
{
    ...
}
```

Note the use of `SelectMany` instead of `Select`. Whenever you have collections of collections, use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548748%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to make it one collection. If you see yourself making a foreach within a foreach, this is a good indication that a `SelectMany` probably would have been a better choice.

Finally: did you see that because of proper use of plurals and singulars the queries are much more readable. Less changes of making mistakes when changes have to be implemented by someone else in future.